# Generating random float points in Julia

Tags: julia

I'm trying solve the question of "Can x * (1/x) ever not be 1 when x is a random floating point number between [1,2]" and I am trying to generate random floating numbers in Julia to test the hypotheses. I've tried doing

```
BigFloat(rand(1,2)), as well as Float64(1,2)
```

to no avail. Any help is appreciated

Comment: First help is to take a night and read: https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/ . Also try `rand(Float64)+1.0` should be pretty uniform between 1.0 and 2.0 (there is the delicate question as to which uniformity you want: on the floating point numbers, or on the reals).

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: @DanGetz dat delicate question tho. +1

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Come to think of it, the floating-points ARE uniformly distributed on [1.0,2.0) (since they all have the same exponent). So generating a uniform [1.0,2.0) number might be more straight forward than a [0.0,1.0). This might be an interesting issue when implementing a `rand(Interval)` type function.

Comment: `rand() + 1`. But this is definitely a homework question addressing the density of floating point numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers is yes

```
for i=1:100
    x = rand() + 1.0;
    xi = 1.0/x
    y = x * xi
    if y != 1.0
        println("case ", i, " x*(1/x) != 1 for x=", x, " diff= ", y - 1.0)
    end
end


case 18 x*(1/x) != 1 for x=1.3193289816663771 diff= -1.1102230246251565e-16
case 26 x*(1/x) != 1 for x=1.9692333690500858 diff= -1.1102230246251565e-16
case 42 x*(1/x) != 1 for x=1.8927527081187694 diff= -1.1102230246251565e-16    
...
```

Aware this is due to the limited precision of floats (doubles). 
This is not true in a mathematical sense.